# How long does it take for a deleted post to get permanently deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I had to delete a question today. How long will it take for it to get permanently deleted and no longer viewable/accessible by anyone?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Never.

Stack Overflow uses "soft deletion". Even if you or another user/moderator hits the delete button on your post, it will still be retained in the system and viewable by the author of the post as well as users with a reputation of >= 10k.

Moderators have the ability to redact portions of posts, such as personally-identifiable information and credentials you might have posted on accident. Simply edit out the portions you need redacted and then custom-flag the post for moderator attention.

Moderators may also escalate requests for post-disassociation (removing your name as author).

If the need is severe enough, you can use the [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) to request a post be permanently deleted by a developer from the databases manually. Just don't expect this option to work; the chances of Stack Exchange following through with these types of request are extremely low.

Comment: relevant MSE post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274274/158100